# How to see the distribution of keys in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

When using a hash map, it's important to evenly distribute the keys over the buckets.

If all keys end up in the same bucket, you essentially end up with a list.

Is there a way to "audit" a HashMap in Java in order to see how well the keys are distributed?

I tried subtyping it and iterating `Entry<K,V>[] table`, but it's not visible.

Comment: Does this help: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal ?

Comment: Your could run a test program in a debugger and inspect what's in the `HashMap` using the debugger.

Comment: You could run a DES encryption algorithm on the keys to generate the hashes which will make sure that the result is random.

Comment: @RahulTripathi this is a lot of overhead, I don't want to do that if it's not necessary.

Comment: Get the source, create your own clone with a built-in "dump distribution" function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I tried subtyping it and iterating Entry[] table, but it's not visible

Use Reflection API!

```
public class Main {
    //This is to simulate instances which are not equal but go to the same bucket.
    static class A {
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) { return false;}

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {return 42; }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Test data  
            HashMap<A, String> map = new HashMap<A, String>(4);
            map.put(new A(), "abc");
            map.put(new A(), "def");

            //Access to the internal table  
            Class clazz = map.getClass();
            Field table = clazz.getDeclaredField("table");
            table.setAccessible(true);
            Map.Entry<Integer, String>[] realTable = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>[]) table.get(map);

            //Iterate and do pretty printing
            for (int i = 0; i < realTable.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Bucket : %d, Entry: %s", i, bucketToString(realTable[i])));
            }
    }

    private static String bucketToString(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry) throws Exception {
            if (entry == null) return null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Access to the "next" filed of HashMap$Node
            Class clazz = entry.getClass();
            Field next = clazz.getDeclaredField("next");
            next.setAccessible(true); 

            //going through the bucket
            while (entry != null) {
                sb.append(entry);
                entry = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) next.get(entry);
                if (null != entry) sb.append(" -> ");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
}
```

---

In the end you'll see something like this in STDOUT:

```
 Bucket : 0, Entry: null 
 Bucket : 1, Entry: null 
 Bucket : 2, Entry: Main$A@2a=abc -> Main$A@2a=def 
 Bucket : 3, Entry: null
```

Comment: Note: this is a really bad idea for production code, but if you're hacking something together for a one-off test it's okay.

Comment: I was actually hoping that HashMap provided some functionality for this that I overlooked, but this is a good second best.

Answer (score 5):

`HashMap` uses the keys produced by the `hashCode()` method of your key objects, so I guess you are really asking how evenly distributed those hash code values are. You can get hold of the key objects using `Map.keySet()`.

Now, the OpenJDK and Oracle implementations of `HashMap` do not use the key hash codes directly,  but apply another hashing function to the provided hashes before distributing them over the buckets. But you should not rely on or use this implementation detail. So you ought to ignore it. So you should just ensure that the `hashCode()` methods of your key values are well distributed.

Examining the actual hash codes of some sample key value objects is unlikely to tell you anything useful unless your hash cide method is *very* poor. You would be better doing a basic theoretical analysis of your hash code method. This is not as scary as it might sound. You may (indeed, have no choice but to do so) assume that the hash code methods of the supplied Java classes are well distributed.  Then you just need a check that the means you use for combining the hash codes for your data members behaves well for the expected values of your data members. Only if your data members have values that are highly correlated in a peculiar way is this likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to access the hidden fields:

```
HashMap map = ...;

// get the HashMap#table field
Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
tableField.setAccessible(true);

Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(map);
int[] counts = new int[table.length];

// get the HashMap.Node#next field
Class<?> entryClass = table.getClass().getComponentType();
Field nextField = entryClass.getDeclaredField("next");
nextField.setAccessible(true);

for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    Object e = table[i];
    int count = 0;
    if (e != null) {
        do {
            count++;
        } while ((e = nextField.get(e)) != null);
    }
    counts[i] = count;
}
```

Now you have an array of the entry counts for each bucket.

Comment: `table[0].getClass();` -- gives `NullPointerException`

Comment: @18446744073709551615 That seems to happen if the first bucket is empy. A safe option would be `table.getClass().getComponentType()`, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Client.java**

```
public class Client{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<Example, Number> m = new HashMap<>();
            Example e1  = new Example(100);  //point 1
            Example e2  = new Example(200);  //point2
            Example e3  = new Example(300);  //point3
            m.put(e1, 10);
            m.put(e2, 20);
            m.put(e3, 30);
            System.out.println(m);//point4
        }
    }
```

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    int s;
    Example(int s) {
        this.s =s;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Now at point 1, point 2 and point 3 in Client.java, we are inserting 3 keys of type Example in hashmap m. Since hashcode() is overridden in Example.java, all three keys e1,e2,e3 will return same hashcode and hence same bucket in hashmap.

Now the problem is how to see the distribution of keys.

Approach :

1. Insert a debug point at point4 in Client.java.
2. Debug the java application.
3. Inspect m.
4. Inside m, you will find table array of type HashMap$Node and size 16.
5. This is literally the hashtable. Each index contains a linked list of Entry objects that are inserted into hashmap. Each non null index has a hash variable that correspond to the hash value returned by the hash() method of Hashmap. This hash value is then sent to indexFor() method of HashMap to find out the index of table array , where the Entry object will be inserted. (Refer @Rahul's link in comments to question to understand the concept of hash and indexFor).
6. For the case, taken above, if we inspect table, you will find all but one key null.
7. We had inserted three keys but we can see only one, i.e. all three keys have been inserted into the same bucket i.e same index of table.
8. Inspect the `table` array element(in this case it will be 5), `key` correspond to e1, while `value` correspond to 10 (point1)
9. `next` variable here points to next node of Linked list i.e. next Entry object which is (e2, 200) in our case.

So in this way you can inspect the hashmap.

Also i would recommend you to go through internal implementation of hashmap to understand HashMap by heart.

Hope it helped..